# Python: Data Transfer Object

Tags: python, ironpython, html-agility-pack

### Problem

I have various html tables that I need to parse/access from my customers web-page, the data on it might vary across the tables (length of columns).

So, what I've done was to create a class for each table but this task became ridiculous, since there are a lot of tables that I need to parse with data varying.

### Question

Is there any way to implement DTOs in python other than creating a class for each data that I what to transfer?

### Example

#### Class

```
class HoldItem():

    @property
    def none1(self):
        return self

    @property
    def none2(self):
        return self

    @property
    def item(self):
        return self

    @property
    def plant(self):
        return self

    @property
    def location(self):
        return self

    @property
    def material(self):
        return self

    @none1.setter
    def none1(self, value):
        self.none1 = value
```

#### Populate Instances

```
items = []
for tds in trs:
    item = HoldItem()

    if (x == PROP_A):
        item.prop_a = tds.InnerText

    ...
    ...
    ...

    items.append(item)

return items
```

#### Transfer to SQLServer Database

```
    for item in items:
        command.AddWithValue("@prop_a", item.prop_a)
```

### Facts

- I'm using Iron Python
- I'm transfering the information into a table (SQL Server)
- I'm using HtmlAgilityPack in order to parse the html table
- I'm web-crawling the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `Messenger` object](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Messenger.html) seems to make sense for your purpose. It is designed as a way to pass data around.

Answer (score 2):

Python is dynamic.

Override `__get__` and `__set__` and store 'field values' in a dictionary internal to your class (instance).